# Download entire FTP directory in Java (Apache Net Commons)

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to recursively iterate through the entire root directory that I arrive at after login to the FTP server.

I am able to connect, all I really want to do from there is recurse through the entire structure and and download each file and folder and have it in the same structure as it is on the FTP. What I have so far is a working download method, it goes to the server and gets my entire structure of files, which is brilliant, except it fails on the first attempt, then works the second time around. The error I get is as follows:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: output-directory\test\testFile.png
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

I managed to do upload functionality of a directory that I have locally, but can't quite get downloading to work, after numerous attempts I really need some help.

```
public static void download(String filename, String base)
{
    File basedir = new File(base);
    basedir.mkdirs();

    try
    {
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftpClient.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles)
        {
            if (!file.getName().equals(".") && !file.getName().equals("..")) {
                // If Dealing with a directory, change to it and call the function again
                if (file.isDirectory())
                {
                    // Change working Directory to this directory.
                    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(file.getName());
                    // Recursive call to this method.
                    download(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory(), base);

                    // Create the directory locally - in the right place
                    File newDir = new File (base + "/" + ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
                    newDir.mkdirs();

                    // Come back out to the parent level.
                    ftpClient.changeToParentDirectory();
                }
                else
                {
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    String remoteFile1 = ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory() + "/" + file.getName();
                    File downloadFile1 = new File(base + "/" + ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory() + "/" + file.getName());
                    OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
                    boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
                    outputStream1.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try and where did it fail?

Comment: Added code to show you my current code the exact way it sits. Thanks for the fast reply by the way.

Comment: Well, what did you try (not the part that is working, the part that you said you tried and failed), and in what way did it fail?

Comment: Helping would indeed be easier if you mentioned which part of the process gives you trouble - downloading the file when you get to it? Traversing remote directiories? Traversing recursively? Preserving folder structure?

Comment: Well, when I had the download code inside the for loop, along with mkdirs() for directory cases, I was finding that I was not getting anywhere near the structure I have in the ftp server back. Also, what I have right now isn't working - it doesn't even manage to print the file or directory names correctly and I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: You are aware that the two first files in each directory are usually `.` and `..`, which are the current directory and the parent directory respectively. You should check for them and skip them or you'll get some very strange results.

Comment: Amended the code with a check (and updated on the example above) - I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop of trying to get the root directory and not really getting down into the other directories

Comment: Comparing strings with `!=`?

Comment: Amended with .equals and it seems to get into the proper directories now. All I need to do is be able to do is actually download the structure correctly. Do you know how I might do that?

Comment: Another Update : I have managed to get it to preserve the correct structure, but when I download anything more complex that a text file, I get back corrupted data. for example, I have a png on my server and the file I download is 1 kb larger than it should be, and doesn't open.

Comment: Yet another update : I have now got it downloading the other file types by using Binary as a transfer mode. Now I have one more issue, on the first attempt, the downloads fail with the error that the filesystem cannot find the file specified. Then when I run it again, it works... Any ideas?

Comment: You should really add all that information to the actual question rather than the comments. I believe editing will bump it up the SO feed. And adding the exact error that you get would also be helpful.

Comment: Added the exact error message - Also added a re-listing of the code and changed the title of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (well, your current problem after we got rid of the `.` and `..` and you got past the binary issue) is that you are doing the recursion step before calling `newDir.mkdirs()`.

So suppose you have a tree like

```
.
..
someDir
   .
   ..
   someFile.txt
someOtherDir
   .
   ..
someOtherFile.png
```

What you do is skip the dot files, see that `someDir` is a directory, then immediately go inside it, skip its dot files, and see `someFile.txt`, and process it. You have not created `someDir` locally as yet, so you get an exception.

Your exception handler does not stop execution, so control goes back to the upper level of the recursion. At this point it creates the directory.

So next time you run your program, the local `someDir` directory is already created from the previous run, and you see no problem.

Basically, you should change your code to:

```
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                // Change working Directory to this directory.
                ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(file.getName());

                // Create the directory locally - in the right place
                File newDir = new File (base + "/" + ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
                newDir.mkdirs();

                // Recursive call to this method.
                download(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory(), base);

                // Come back out to the parent level.
                ftpClient.changeToParentDirectory();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a million for all of your help here! This has easily been the best help I have ever gotten on stack overflow, you had me working through my problem myself and making the necessary changes I needed as I went along. Rather than just being given a lump of code, I learned a few neat new things :)

Answer (score 1):

A complete standalone code to download all files recursively from an FTP folder:

```
private static void downloadFolder(
    FTPClient ftpClient, String remotePath, String localPath) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Downloading folder " + remotePath + " to " + localPath);

    FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(remotePath);

    for (FTPFile remoteFile : remoteFiles)
    {
        if (!remoteFile.getName().equals(".") && !remoteFile.getName().equals(".."))
        {
            String remoteFilePath = remotePath + "/" + remoteFile.getName();
            String localFilePath = localPath + "/" + remoteFile.getName();

            if (remoteFile.isDirectory())
            {
                new File(localFilePath).mkdirs();

                downloadFolder(ftpClient, remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Downloading file " + remoteFilePath + " to " +
                    localFilePath);

                OutputStream outputStream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFilePath));
                if (!ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, outputStream))
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to download file " + remoteFilePath);
                }
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```